# How to distinguish headers and data from bytes returned from stream handle event in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i have written method which downloads image form web URL in objective c.I am using CFWriteStream and CFReadStream as suggested at

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/NetworkStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002277-SW1

In handleevent delegate of stream i am getting all the response data in one shot and not able to distinguish between header and image data.
In this case if i am writing all data to an image file then the file not opening.
:(

Comment: Why don't you use NSURLConnection? That gives you a NSHTTPURLResponse object (with the header data) and the content data separately. It also handles compression transparently.

Comment: Do you have to use something as low-level as `CFReadStream`? It would be much simpler if you could use a higher level API such as `NSURLRequest` with `NSURLConnection`.

Comment: Thanks.But i need network socket stream similar to request.getrequestStream() in c#.